# SQL Server : dynamic database name in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure with dynamic db name. But I can't get it run after I specify the parameters

```
@BatchStartTime = N'2013/12/26 15:00:00',
@BatchEndTime = N'2013/12/26 15:30:00',
@DBName = N'MYDATABASE'
```

Here are my sample code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[newSpMurexTest]
    @BatchStartTime AS VARCHAR(30),
    @BatchEndTime AS VARCHAR(30),
    @DBName AS VARCHAR(30)
AS  BEGIN
       declare @vwAllTrans nvarchar(max)

       set @vwAllTrans = N'select T.fin_payAmt, C.fin_midAmt, C.myr_equivalent from '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) +'.dbo.tbl_transaction_history as H 
                       inner join '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.dbo.tbl_transaction_cancellation as C on H.transaction_id = C.trans_id
                      inner join '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) +'.dbo.tbl_transaction as T on H.transaction_id = T.transaction_id
                      where  H.dt_last_chg >=  @BatchStartTime  H.dt_last_chg <= @BatchEndTime and (H.new_status IN (7))'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @vwAllTrans
                          ,'@BatchStartTime AS VARCHAR(30), @BatchEndTime AS VARCHAR(30)'
                          , @BatchStartTime, @BatchEndTime
END
```

I can run the query if I remove the `@vwAllTrans`, directly select it and replace the `@dbname`, `@BatchStartTime`, and `@BatchEndTime`.. do I mess up the query when it put it under `@vwAllTrans` and exec it?

Comment: is this mysql or sql server ??

Comment: is it possible that your BatchStartTime, BatchEndTime or DBName is null?

Comment: no, i have make sure that the BatchStartTime, BatchEndTime or DBName is not null..this is microsoft sql server

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[newSpMurexTest]
@BatchStartTime  AS NVARCHAR(30),
@BatchEndTime    AS NVARCHAR(30),
@DBName          AS NVARCHAR(30)

AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;   

declare @vwAllTrans nvarchar(max)
set @vwAllTrans = N'select T.fin_payAmt, C.fin_midAmt, C.myr_equivalent from '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.tbl_transaction_history as H 
                  inner join '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.tbl_transaction_cancellation as C on H.transaction_id = C.trans_id
                  inner join '+ QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.tbl_transaction as T on H.transaction_id = T.transaction_id
                  where  H.dt_last_chg >=  @BatchStartTime AND H.dt_last_chg <= @BatchEndTime and H.new_status IN (7)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @vwAllTrans
                      ,N'@BatchStartTime AS NVARCHAR(30), @BatchEndTime AS NVARCHAR(30)'
                      , @BatchStartTime, @BatchEndTime
END

GO
```

Comment: Have you tested your query passing hardcoded values does it work then ??

Comment: Run it Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: @user2085499 try now I think you had an extra set or paranthesis.

Comment: Same error-Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. Sorry i'm just started with sql. Yesterday i learn how to insert, today i have to modify this stored procedure..LOL

Comment: Change datatype of your variables to `NVARCHAR` from `VARCHAR` and prefix any string concatenations with `N` see my update.

Comment: Yes it work m.Ali, but when i execute it by using "Execute store procedure it' return me two table?.. how to disable the return value table?

Comment: You mean it returns two messages. all you need to do is use `SET NOCOUNT ON;` after the BEGIN in your proc see my update and please accept the answer if it helped thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much m.Ali. Last question, if i want to add a case, how can i do it? set @vwAllTrans = N'select T.fin_payAmt, C.fin_midAmt, CASE WHEN H.new_status = 7 THEN 'Refund Principal' WHEN H.new_status = 8 THEN 'Refund Fee' ELSE 'Send Principal' END AS trxn_label2,